# Given 2 digits and 3 letters, how many different license plates are possible without a repeated symbol?

Tags: combinatorics

The plate has 2 digits followed by 3 letters. How many different plates are there without a repeated symbol? I know how to get every single possibility (10 * 10 * 26 * 26 * 26), but that includes repeated symbols.

Comment: Hint:   If you allow 10 digits in the first slot, you have only 9 remaining digits for the second slot...

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Without repeated number for the first number, you would have 10 options, now having 1 number, for the second number there are only 9 options left since you can't repeat the first one. The same goes for the alphabet first letter has 26 options, second one 25, the third one 24.

Hence every possibility = $(10 * 9 * 26 * 25 * 24)$

Comment: Great, thank you for responding!